# Getting text from textarea of containers with Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, textarea

I'm trying to retrieve text from a text box of containers/cards from [this google forms](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1MYSjxAMCXMXB02GPXqkewVx35_ptzv0XO7GRZQGwyGE/edit). Basically I want to retrieve the questions and the related answers.

Question Test boxes inside a container have more or less the following html code:

```xml
<textarea 
class="appsMaterialWizTextinputTextareaInput exportTextarea" 
jsname="YPqjbf" 
data-rows="0" 
tabindex="0" 
aria-label="Intitulé de la question" 
jscontroller="RKFxf" 
jsaction="input:Lg5SV;ti6hGc:XMgOHc;rcuQ6b:WYd;" 
data-disable-newlines="true" 
dir="auto" 
data-initial-dir="auto" 
data-initial-value="How do you feel about your next vacation after COVID-19?" 
style="height: 24px;">
How do you feel about your next vacation after COVID-19?
</textarea>
```

I thought my code could do it, but the result is blank:

```
# I get all the card with questions and answers inside
containers = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(
    "freebirdFormeditorViewItemcardRoot.item-dlg-affectsIndex.item-dlg-dragTarget"
)
print("containers: ", containers)

# for each card
for container in containers:
    try:
        # Get the question
        question = container.find_element_by_class_name(
            "appsMaterialWizTextinputTextareaInput.exportTextarea"
        )
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("NoSuchElementException: ")
        continue
    print("question: ", question.text)
```

The result

```
question:
```

Nothing ... It seems that question gets all the textarea and not the one specific to the card/container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to get it by the aria-label attribute using CSS selector like following :

```
question = container.find_element_by_css_selector(".exportTextarea[aria-label='Intitulé de la question']")
```

Selenium can't get an element that has multiple classes with `find_element_by_class_name` the only way to achieve that is using CSS selector like this :

```
find_element_by_css_selector("classOne classTwo")
```

Comment: Thanks ! Do you know why it wasn't working the other way? Another problem is that I think that Google set these aria-label according to my browser default language that it detects. But how can it be adaptable to other browsers?

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica problem with selenium is you can't get an element using 'find_element_by_class_name'  in the case where element has multiple classes you can achieve that  only by CSS selector, and about the aria-label issue being changing try this: `driver.find_elements_by_class_name("appsMaterialWizTextinputTextareaInput exportTextarea")` with a space between classes, not a dot